# Why is Firefox totally ignoring some of my CSS?

Tags: css, firefox, css-float

I am using Firefox 21 on Mountain Lion.  I have some divs that are being created by JavaScript via:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        setup_teaching_points();
     });
```

The code below works fine in Chrome.  Firefox doesn't apply any CSS to teaching_point_opener_wrapper.

```
     <style type='text/css'>
       (...other css, none of which touches the class in question here)
       div.teaching_point_opener_wrapper { width:20px; float:right }
     </style>

     <div class="teaching_point_opener_wrapper">
        (...stuff)
     </div>
```

The only thing I can think of is that Firefox is applying CSS before my divs are created and not attempting to apply any rules to them after creation.  This seems bonkers...but then, so many things are.

What's going on here?

edit:
Somebody shoot me.  It was this a few lines above...

```
      div#diagram_results_and_thumbnail {width:25%'}
```

I guess Chrome is smarter about me being careless than FireFox is.

Comment: It's not applying CSS before your divs are created...it doesn't work like JS. Can you post us a jsfiddle? Have you tried inspecting the `div` to check whether or not the styles are there/are being overwritten?

Comment: The big upside to having FireFox problems is that you can use firebug to solve them.  Check it out - I think it's the best browser tool for devs.  http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Can you please post the 'other css' bits in their entirety?  Chances are those are in fact affecting the rule in question.

Comment: Yup, it was the 'other css'.  Would firebug have pointed that out nicely for me?  I am much more used to Chrome's tools.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the answer, but not the underlying cause.  Firefox seems to cache page content differently to other browsers.  I've just been developing a webpage and notice how some edits are updated in Firefox but not others - not just CSS but also HTML edits.  If you open the page in a fresh window it should update properly.  But deleting cache and recent activity didn't update it.  In fact I needed to open an incognito window to display the fresh content!  Why this happens is beyond me.